# Exporting Neo4j database for importing in another Neo4j-desktop application

Tags: database, neo4j, export

I should say, that neo4j-admin tools didnt work for me.

```
    neo4j-admin dump --database=<database-name>  --to=<database-address>
```

and i get an error every time, that database doesnt exist.

so is there any other way to export my Neo4j database ??

```
C:\Users\Shafigh\.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-2912eb35-11ba-4ae1- 
b5b9-cb4b88a6f0a9\installation-3.4.7\bin> neo4j-admin dump --database=test_1  
--to=C:/Users/Shafigh/Desktop/files
org.neo4j.commandline.admin.CommandFailed: database does not exist: test_1
at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.DumpCommand.execute(DumpCommand.java:83)
at org.neo4j.commandline.admin.AdminTool.execute(AdminTool.java:127)
at org.neo4j.commandline.admin.AdminTool.main(AdminTool.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Directory 
'C:\Users\Shafigh\.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-2912eb35-11ba-4ae1- 
b5b9-cb4b88a6f0a9\installation-3.4.7\data\databases\test_1' does not contain 
a database
    at 
  org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Validators.lambda$static$3(Validators.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.DumpCommand.execute(DumpCommand.java:79)
    ... 2 more
command failed: database does not exist: test_1
```

[snapshot of my Neo4j desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK5AF.jpg)

[graph_db size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F8l4.jpg)

Comment: Can you show what directory you are running the "dump" command in, the actual command that you use, and what error you are seeing? Likely, you just need to tweak things a b it to get "dump" to work.

Comment: @ cybersam: I updated my post

Comment: Do you actually have a DB at the path `C:\Users\Shafigh\.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-2912eb35-11ba-4ae1- 
b5b9-cb4b88a6f0a9\installation-3.4.7\data\databases\test_1`?

Comment: sure, but I gave  test_1 in neo4j environment, but at above path, there is ...\data\databases\graph.db (folder) , so where is my test_1 ?

Comment: Show how you configured the path for `test_1`.

Comment: I don't understand your tone. I am trying to help, and I just need more information. [Here is more info on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In fact, I just provided an Answer...

Comment: I dont have much experience with Neo4j, i.e i can not answer all the details you are looking for, if I could i would have not asked questions, which look likes funny to you but important to me

Comment: Relax. We are all friends here :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test_1` is just the name of your Neo4j Desktop "project". It is not the name of your "database".

Use this command line instead (which uses the default database name, which is what you are using):

```
neo4j-admin dump --database=graph.db --to=C:/Users/Shafigh/Desktop/files
```

[UPDATED with more details, from my comments]

Neo4j Desktop is an environment that allows you to have many projects, with each project having possibly multiple DBs and plugins with different versions. So, your "test_1" is just the name of your project. Within that project, each DB will have its own directory structure, and by default the directory in that structure that contains your DB is given the name "graph.db". You can change the name of that DB if you want by setting the `dbms.active_database` property in that DB's `neo4j.conf` file -- but that is rarely useful.

Comment: so graph.db is a reserved name and it is created automatically every time? so as far as I know, test_1 is Graph Name.  At the bottom left of pic, that I posted, shows database symbol beside test_1. So what is really test_1? and if graph.db is set by system every time, why is the usage of graph naming ?

Comment: Neo4j Desktop is an environment that allows you to have many projects, with each project having possibly multiple DBs and plugins with different versions. So, your "test_1" is just the name of your project. Within that project, each DB will have its own directory structure, and by default the directory in that structure that contains your DB is given the name "graph.db". You can change the name of that DB if you want  by setting the `dbms.active_database` property in that DB's `neo4j.conf` file, but that is rarely useful.

Comment: I posted another snapshot. I run the code with graph.db as db name, dump size created is 21 mb, which is in contrast with the size of graph.db i am seeing in Neo4j Dektop.

Comment: There is no need for the 2 to have the same size, as long as you get back the same data when you `load` from the dumped file.

Comment: I reloaded created dump and it is as same as original database. So thank you very much @Cybersam. I tried to change db name as you recommended, but it doesnt affect at all, even I created new Graph name and changed the db name, but after I run the instance, graph.db was still the db name, I just wanted to give feedback, but this one is not so important to me, also cheers !